# запуск окна WPF из dll

Tags: c#, xaml

При запуске программа обращается к DLL и вызывает функцию Init(), после чего открывается окно Windows.Forms.

```
public class MainForm
{
    static Form1 mainform;
    static Thread threadmainform;

    [DllExport]
    public static void Init()
    {
        if (mainform == null)
        {
            threadmainform = new Thread(NewForm);
            threadmainform.Start();
        }
    }

    [DllExport]
    public static void DeInit(int reason)
    {
        if (reason == 3 || reason == 5) return;
        if (mainform != null) { mainform.Close(); Thread.Sleep(1000); }
        if (threadmainform != null) threadmainform.Join();
        mainform = null;
        threadmainform = null;
    }

    private static void NewForm() { mainform = new Form1(); mainform.ShowDialog(); }
}
```

сейчас у меня получилось совместить WPF и dll, но не получается запустить окна таким же образом.
Подскажите как это исправить? Я не программист, если можно то какой нибудь пример кода.

Comment: А откуда запускаете? Из C++?

Comment: Программа МетаТрейдер4, Скорее всего да...С++